# Using Scrapy to parse sitemaps

Tags: python, sitemap, scrapy

I want to be able to use scrapy to crawl links on a sitemap. I don't know much about this application, so I would be interested in any links/info/documentation you could provide.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A new generic spider has just been added to Scrapy trunk, for this purpose. It will be available on next release (Scrapy 0.14)

- Code here: http://snippets.scrapy.org/snippets/20/
- Documentation here: http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#sitemapspider

Answer (score 0):

All of the documentation is at http://doc.scrapy.org/. The tutorials can be found at scrapy.org also.

As for your question, see this SO question: [how to parse a sitemap.xml file using scrapy's XmlFeedSpider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598895/how-to-parse-a-sitemap-xml-file-using-scrapys-xmlfeedspider)