# Getting sub URLs from a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I would like to know if it is possible to list URLs from a website. Those URLs are the ones hosting zip files and if you provided them correctly, files will be downloaded. If not, you are directed to a 404 page.

For example, if the main site is `https://myexample.net/`, I am interested in files under `https://myexample.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/[do not have a pattern].zip`. I tried to access `https://myexample.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/`, but got a `404 error`.

In addition, I checked `https://myexample.net/sitemap_index.xml`, but did not find those URLs of my interests. So the question is how to `guess` those URLs... Appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: `https://myexample.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/` probably displays the listing of the zip files, the HTML of which could be scraped. Could you post your actual link? It would make it much easier to write a working solution.

Comment: @Ajax1234, thanks for your suggestion. I tried to access `https://myexample.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/`, but got a `404 error...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a [sitemap generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857653/get-a-list-of-urls-from-a-site)?

There is a python library for it as well: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sitemap-generator/0.5.2

There are also browser plugins to do this if you don't want to code, such as "uSelect iDownload" tool for Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for providing those resources! Will check them out.

Comment: @TH339 please mark this as solved.

Comment: @W4t3randWind, Sorry, I do not think my question has been solved...

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know if it is possible to list URLs from a website?

Now if you are talking about a specific website or any generic website.

I have done decent amount of scraping using Scrapy for years. Now below is my experience

1. Many sites don't use sitemaps at all
2. Sites that do use sitemaps have a very old sitemap which was updated long back
3. Latest sitemap generated only has limited urls and not all the urls

So all in all, sitemaps can be good for generating a list of seed urls, but they are controlled by the website administrator and they may or may keep sitemaps updated. So if you really want a list of urls, you need to use crawling. If you don't want to use code for the same, then you can look few approach discussed in below threads

[Spider a Website and Return URLs Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804467/spider-a-website-and-return-urls-only)

If you want to go the coding I would suggest you have a look at Scrapy

[Scrapy crawl all sitemap links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957267/scrapy-crawl-all-sitemap-links)

[Using Scrapy to parse sitemaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335906/using-scrapy-to-parse-sitemaps/6360675#6360675)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In terms of the real URLs, is there a way I can share you privately?

Comment: You can message me LI http://linkedin.com/in/tarunlalwani